# How to create a clickable shape with SVG and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src='draw.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="600" height="200"></svg>
</body>

</html>
```

draw.js

```
function draw() {
    var svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
    var svgNS = svg.namespaceURI;

    var rect = document.createElementNS(svgNS,'rect');
    rect.setAttribute('x',5);
    rect.setAttribute('y',5);
    rect.setAttribute('width',100);
    rect.setAttribute('height',36);
    rect.setAttribute('fill','#95B3D7');

    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('xlink:href', 'http://www.google.com');
    link.appendChild(rect);
    svg.appendChild(link);
}

$( document ).ready( draw );
```

The generated HTML looks correct, but the rectangle does not appear:

`<a xlink:href="http://www.google.com">
    <rect x="5" y="5" width="100" height="36" fill="#95B3D7"></rect>
</a>`

In fact, the generated HTML does work, when pasted into an HTML file. So, is there some limitation of the browser using SVG, Javascript and links?

Using Chrome 39.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an SVG link element and not a html link element i.e. in the SVG namespace

```
var link = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'a');
link.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', 'http://www.google.com');
```

You get it right for the rect itself!